# "Each day" or "with each day". What's the difference in meaning?

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning, sentence-meaning

"...and (with?) each day my confidence grows strong that..."

"How can I make sure that (with) each day I memorize more?"

Are these with-s redundant? Do they change the meaning of these sentences at all?

Answer (score 1):

“with each” can be used for a progression, but the “with” is optional:

- With each day, I grow stronger.
- Each day, I grow stronger.

Both have an implied “than the previous day”.

You can’t use “with” when each day is the same:

- Each day, I am strong.

Answer (score 0):

'Each day' implies present tense or something is actively being done today.
'With each day' seems to imply past tense, or something had already been done in the past.

Either way is acceptable.